# Swift require protocol extension

Tags: swift, protocols

If I have

```
protocol AppearingTextContainer {
  func clipBounds() -> ()
}
extension AppearingTextContainer where Self: UIView {
  func clipBounds() { self.clipsToBounds = true }
}
```

then a class that adopts my protocol CustomView: AppearingTextContainer is not forced by the compiler to implement clipBounds. If I remove the extension it won't compile. Is there any way to enforce CustomView to call clipBounds without having to delete the default clipBounds implementation?

Thanks

Comment: It's a little unclear what you mean by "is not forced by the compiler to call `clipBounds`". What would call `clipBounds` in the first place? You aren't showing enough of your code to make this clear. Also won't compile why? Because you didn't conform to the protocol, presumably...

Comment: If you want to force to implement `clipBounds` method then why are you extending with default implentation

Comment: sorry yeah I am a little unclear myself, just getting used to protocols.  Basically I want whatever adopts my protocol to require a method that calls some default extension methods

Comment: ok a more simple way to put it is I want whatever adopts my protocol to automatically clipToBounds, or force a method that calls the clipBounds in the extension

Comment: When you extend protocol with default implementation then if class who is conforming does not implement that method then its default value is taken otherwise it takes new value

Answer (score 0):

If your custom view class has its own `clipBounds` function, then you would have to cast your custom view to an AppearingTextContainer in order to get the AppearingTextContainer protocol extension implementation.

But keep in mind that Objective-C cannot see your protocol extension, so Cocoa will never call the protocol extension `clipBounds` for you; only a direct Swift call can call it.

Answer (score 0):

You've only provided a method that will become available to any UIView that chooses to conform to `AppearingTextContainer`.

So now ideally you would create a UIView subclass that conforms

```
class AppearingTextView: UIView, AppearingTextContainer {
  // you can now call clipBounds() on this class
}
```

or

```
extension UIView: AppearingTextView { }
```

what I think you should consider is whether or not what you really want is a protocol extension vs. just an extension on UIView:

```
extension UIView {
  func clipsBounds() -> Void { clipsToBounds = true }
}
```

if you want a protocol, I suggest going the route of:

```
protocol ClippingView {
  var clipsToBounds: Bool { get set }
}

extension ClippingView {
  func clipsBounds() -> Void { clipsToBounds = true }
}

extension UIView: ClippingView { }

let clippingViews: [ClippingView] = [......]

clippingViews.forEach { $0.clipsBounds() }
```